# How to import yahoo, gmail contacts in my JSF application

Tags: java, jsf, gmail, yahoo-mail

How can I import yahoo, gmail contacts in my application by giving username and password using JSF? I want to do functionality of send invitation from my application.

Comment: This not quite related to JSF.